# Position UINavbar IOS 7 and IOS 8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

I am carrying out a simple application that uses the UINavigationBar. 
I developed while I noticed this problem. 
If the UINavigationToolbar use IOS 7 is positioned with a difference of a few pixels (figure 1), while if use IOS 8, the UINavigationToolbar is positioned correctly (figure 2). 
What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks,
Vincenzo
[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Please add more information. How are you placing the nav bar? IB or code? setFrame or autolayout?

Comment: Sorry. I add navigation with ib with embedded -> uinavgation tool bar

Comment: please be clear, did you embed in a navigation controller?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry if I was not clear. I had a simple ViewController. Via the menu item Editor, Clip In, Navigation Controler I entered the UINavigationController and then I did nothing. All this of course by using the Storyboard. Then when I went to try the simulator, but the same problem with the device, if IOS is version 7 then I created that problem, or if the version of IOS is 8 there are no problems. Yes i use Autolayout.

Comment: do you have default.png files for iphone 4 and iphone 5?

Comment: No but i think no problem of default.png. With iOS 8 is function without problem

Comment: I'm sure that is the problem. iOS 7.1 and up can use LaunchScreen.xib, but iOS 7 needs default.png for iPhone 5. Please add that and check.

Comment: Ok this evening i try with default.png file